# Initialising a two dimensional array within a class via the constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, initialization, c++14

I have a matrix class in which I'd like to be able to initialise the values of the two dimensional data array with a bracketed list. I find that I can achieve this via declaring a 2D array before calling the constructor, and then passing this as the constructor argument. However, I'd prefer to be able to pass the bracketed list directly as the argument.

```
template <class T, unsigned int N, unsigned int M>
class Matrix
{
    T data[N][M];

    Matrix(const T initMat[N][M])
    {
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<N; ++i)
        {
            for (unsigned int j=0; j<M; ++j)
            {
                data[i][j] = initMat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
};




const double arr[2][2] = {{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}};
Matrix<double, 2, 2> matA(arr);    // Valid


Matrix<double, 2, 2> matB({{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}});    // Invalid
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried using nested std::arrays to no avail (presumably because they act the same way as c-style arrays). Would it be possible to achieve this through an initialiser-list? (I have tried using init-lists but I'm unsure if they're unsuitable or if they just don't behave as I expect them to.)

I am using gcc and c++14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a constructor like:

```
Matrix(std::array<std::array<T, M>, N> const& initMat) { ... }
```

And add another set of curly-braces (for the `std::array` object):

```
Matrix<double, 2, 2> matB({{{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}}});
```

---

Or use `std::initialize_list` like:

```
Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>>){}
```

And then you can drop the parentheses (and one pair of curly-braces) from the above definition:

```
Matrix<double, 2, 2> matB{{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}};
```

The drawback with this is that the sizes of the initializer lists won't be enforced. Therefore I recommend the first variant, using `std::array`.

Comment: Can you explain why we have to use these additional curly brackets?

Comment: @AndreasH. They are for the `std::array` object itself.

Comment: Very neat usage of *std::array* !

Comment: Thank you! I thought I tried this before but must of missed something. Thank you for also explaining the usage for std::initializer_list